# Question about one proof of $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\int_Xe^{|f_n(x)|}-1\right)d\mu(x)=0$ implying $f_n\overset{L^p}{\to}0,\forall p\in\Bbb N$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Suppose $(X,\mathcal F,\mu)$ is a measure space and $(f_n)_{n\in\Bbb  N}$ is a sequence of measurable functions $X\to\Bbb R$ s. t. $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_X\left(e^{|f_n(x)|}-1\right)d\mu=0.$$ Prove that, for each $p\in\Bbb N,$ $f_n\overset{L^p}{\to}0.$

Here is one answer that I've seen and I have a question regarding the last, but one line.

> \begin{align}\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_X\sum_{p=1}^\infty|f_n(x)|^p\frac1{p!}d\mu(x)&=0\\\overset{\text{monotone convergence theorem }}{\Leftrightarrow}\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{p=1}^\infty\frac1{p!}\int_X|f_n(x)|^pd\mu(x)&=0\\\Leftrightarrow\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{p=1}^\infty\frac1{p!}\|f_n\|_p^p&=0\\\Rightarrow\sum_{p=1}^\infty\frac1{p!}\lim_{n\to\infty}\|f_n\|_p^p&=0\\\Rightarrow\lim_{n\to\infty}\|f_n\|_p^p&=0,\forall p\in\mathbb N.\end{align}

As it stands, is this answer valid, or should we, instead, do as follows (?):

Once we obtained $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{p=1}^\infty\frac1{p!}\|f_n\|_p^p=0,$$ we know that, for a given $k\in\mathbb N$ there is $n\in\Bbb N$ s. t. $$0\le\sum_{p=1}^\infty\frac1{p!}\|f_m\|_p^p<\frac1{k!},\forall m\in\mathbb N,m\ge n$$ This, in turn, means $\frac1{p!}\|f_m\|_p^p<\frac1{k!}\forall m\in\mathbb N,m\ge n\text{ and }\forall p\in\mathbb N,$ which, in turn, means $$\frac{k!}{p!}\|f_m\|_p^p<1,\forall p\in\mathbb N,\forall m\ge n.$$ So, I obtained: $$(\forall k\in\Bbb N)(\exists n\in\Bbb N)(\forall p\in\Bbb N)\left((m\ge n)\Rightarrow\left(\frac{k!}{p!}\|f_m\|_p^p<1\right)\right),$$ but, $$\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{k!}{p!}=+\infty,\forall p\in\mathbb N,$$ therefore, to achieve $$\frac{k!}{p!}\|f_m\|_p^p<1,$$ we need $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\|f_n\|_p^p=0,\forall p\in\Bbb N.$$

Any advice would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If the limit of an infinite sum $\sum_p a_{n,p}$ with nonnegative terms is equal $0,$ then the limit of each single term $a_{n,p_0}$ is $0$ as $0\le a_{n,p_0}\le \sum_p a_{n,p}.$

Comment: @KennyWong, I hope you don't mind my rollback. We used to say :" $(X,\mathcal F)$ is a measurable space, while $(X,\mathcal F,\mu)$ is a measure space."

Comment: $x+1\leq e^x$ for all $x$. In particular $|f_n|\leq e^{|f_n|}-1$.  This implies that $\|f\|_1\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$. Similarly, for all $x>0$ and $m\in\mathbb{N}$, $\sum^m_{k=1}\frac{x^k}{k!}\leq e^x-1$.